# Private key gets into the build

Tags: git, github, environment-variables, create-react-app

My private key is showing up in the build. GitHub automatically deletes the key of its API, which are in the public.

[image]

I run `npm run build` and the key gets into the build. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The moment you reference it in your code, you pull it in there. Is it also in your build output if you don't reference it?

Comment: Hello. I did not understand you. I indicate my secret key in .env. further in the repositories Slice.tsx uses it. I don't list my key anywhere other than .env. But when deployed, it still ends up in gh-pages in clear tex

Comment: You say that `Slice.tsx` uses it and then you say it doesn't. Which of the two statements is true?